# Delete old tmp file when Apache starts

Tags: apache, mamp, bitnami

I'm using Bitnami MAMP Stack on OSX and would like to clear the tmp directory whenever I start the Apache Web Server.

So basically I need to know where to add the following command, or a script containing the command `rm -rf ~/Library/Containers/com.bitnami.mampstack/Data/app/php/tmp`.

Takk,
Robert.

Answer (score 0):

Just look inside your MAMP program folder. There is ./bin/start.sh
Just add you line to this.
Or to startApache.sh if you want to execute only with Apache restarts.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but I can't find those files. I first tried `cd /Applications/MampStack.app/` and `find . -name start*` then to make sure I didn't misunderstand you I went to `cd ~/Library/Containers/com.bitnami.mampstack/` and executed the find command again. Hmmm... I'm actually using the Bitnami MAMP Stack - http://bitnami.com/stack/mamp so maybe that's different? Didn't think about that before. :-)